# Compare two lists : One contain object, one other contain string

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to compare two list to add (in an other list) my lights that I want.
I want to get **light object** by **string name**

For the moment, I'm using a double foreach, but I know it's possible with LinQ but I don't know how...

```
private readonly string[] lightsWanted = { "MyLight1", "MyLight2" };
---
var lights = await this.bridgeManager.GetLights();
foreach (Light light in lights)
{
    foreach (string lightWanted in this.lightsWanted)
    {
        if (light.Name == lightWanted)
        {
            this.selectedLights.Add(light);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Join for the purpose

```
var selectedList = lights.Join(lightsWanted,x=>x.Name,y=>y,(x,y)=>x);
```

Comment: I like this method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a Where and Contains (not as efficient).

```
List<Light> lightsIWant = (await this.bridgeManager.GetLights())
    .Where(l => lightsWanted.Contains(l.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Using a Join (more efficient)

```
var allLights = await this.bridgeManager.GetLights();
IEnumerable<Light> lightsIWant = from allLight in allLights
                                 join desiredLightName in lightsWanted 
                                     on allLight.Name equals desiredLightName
                                 select allLight;
```

You can do a Join using Extension Methods as well, I just prefer using the query syntax for simple stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
List<Light> lightsIwant = (from l in lights
                           join lw in lightsWanted on l.Name equals lw
                           select l).ToList();
```